# What are the exact meanings and differences using these values in JS : ${abc} vs {abc} vs (abc)

Tags: javascript, function, curly-braces, dollar-sign

What are the exact meanings and differences using these values in JS : `${abc}` vs `{abc}` vs `(abc)`

Comment: None of those appear to be Booleans. All of that syntax has different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:reactjs], [tag:function], and [tag:react-functional-component]? This doesn't seem to be related to any of those (although one of the aforementioned different contexts for `{...}` is in JSX which is commonly used with React)

Comment: `${abc}` is the syntax for a substitution in a template literal (```console.log(`abc is ${abc}`);```). `{abc}` is a JSX expression you'd use in a JSX context (`<input type="text" disabled={abc} />`). `(abc)` is just a variable reference within parentheses (which are unnecessary when the only thing inside them is a variable reference).

Comment: thanks all for your valuable feedbacks I've updated the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

None of those have to be boolean values. `${abc}` is used inside template strings to embed an expression inside a string.

```js
`foo ${abc} bar`
```

is equivalent to

```js
"foo " + abc + " bar"
```

`{abc}` is an object shorthand notation that's equivalent to `{abc: abc}`. `(abc)` is just `abc` surrounded by parenthesis, which is equivalent to `abc`.